# How can I mock a private final field?

Tags: java, dictionary, junit, mockito

I have the class below:

```java
Class Test{
  private final Map<String, Map<BigInteger, String>> holder = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public boolean checkIfExists(String key){
      return holder.containsKey(key);
  }
}
```

I want to write test case for checkIfExists, How do I mock *holder* i.e Map in this scenario.

Comment: I do not think that you should mock that. It is an internal/private part of the Test class, so I think you should just use the class instance to do whatever you want. Let's say you want to test "checkIfExists" for a key. Just put values using class's public API, and then use check method to test that. Mocking would be useful if the initial value of the "holder" was coming from outside (injected)

Answer (score 0):

Better way for doing that, is creating a constructor having as an argument the holder attribute, then, you can mock it, or use an stub.

```
Class Test{
  private final Map<String, Map<BigInteger, String>> holder;

  public Test(final Map<String, Map<BigInteger, String>> holder){
    this.holder = holder;
  }

  public boolean checkIfExists(String key){
    return holder.containsKey(key);
  }
}
```